# Python Bar Plot pylab not reading in all data from csv

Tags: python, list, csv, matplotlib

I am attempting to create a bar plot of a large text file of data that looks like the following, storedd in a csv file:

```
#DowntonPBS, 23
#DowntonAbbey, 12
#Download, 8
#Download:, 2
#Downloads, 2
#DownstairsMixtape, 1
#DownWithAssad, 1
#DownYoTLParty, 1
#DowntonAbbey?, 1
#Downtonabbey, 1
#DowntownAbbey, 1
```

The following code is where I'm at, and while this method has worked in the past for different plotting scripts, I've done something wrong here that I just can't seem to find. Instead of plotting all of the data, I only seem to be getting three records.

```
import pylab as p                                                                                                                                                       
import sys                                                                                                                                                              
from matplotlib.mlab import csv2rec                                                                                                                                     

y = []                                                                                                                                                                  

fig = p.figure()                                                                                                                                                        
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)                                                                                                                                             

input = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')                                                                                                                                          

data = csv2rec(input, names=['tag', 'count'])                                                                                                                           

for item in data['count']:
        y.append(item)

N = len(y)

ind = range(N)

ax.bar(ind, y, align='center')

ax.set_ylabel('Counts')

ax.set_title('HashTag Diversity')

ax.set_xticks(ind)

group_labels = data['tag']

ax.set_xticklabels(group_labels)

fig.autofmt_xdate()

p.show()
```

If I add print statements for y and N, and run the script against my larger dataset I end up with:

```
[45, 37, 36]
3
```

These values should be a very large array "1000" values and the lenth (N) should = 1000. I'm not sure what's going on here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`csv2rec()` will ignore lines startswith "#" by default, you can change this by:

```
csv2rec(input, names=['tag', 'count'], comments="something")
```